# En un ListView se ejecutan dos eventos a la vez (setOnItemClickListener y setOnItemLongClickListener)

Tags: android

En una actividad tengo un ListView. Al seleccionar uno de los elementos del ListView quiero abrir otra actividad dependiendo de como sea la pulsación: corta o larga.

He asignado a ListView los eventos `setOnItemSelectedListener` y `setOnItemLongClickListener` pero la pulsación corta no hace nada. Si hago una pulsación larga si se ejecuta el evento `setOnItemLongClickListener`.

He probado también con el `setOnItemClickListener` pero tiene el inconveniente de que se ejecuta a la vez que el evento `setOnItemLongClickListener` provocando que se abran dos actividades.

```java
        listViewTiendas.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    listViewTiendas.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent lanzadera = new Intent(ActTiendaSeleccionar.this, ActCrudEquipos.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("objTienda", listaTiendas.get(position));
    bundle.putSerializable("objEmpresa", empresa);
    lanzadera.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(lanzadera);
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent lanzadera = new Intent(ActTiendaSeleccionar.this, ActEquiposRedes.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("objTienda", listaTiendas.get(position));
    bundle.putSerializable("objEmpresa", empresa);
    lanzadera.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(lanzadera);
  }
```

Comment: Hice una simple prueba y funciona perfectamente con onItemClick y onItemLongClick. OnItemSelectedListener según la documentación es para cuando se ha seleccionado un item, entiendo que con seleccionar un item se refiere a "dejar seleccionado" como si fuera un CheckBox, no lo tengo claro (nunca lo usé y estoy aprendiendo), pero te animo a muestres como has creado el adaptador y que pruebes otra vez con setOnItemLongClickListner y setOnItemClickListener, deberían de funcionar, de no ser así algo hay por ahí que lo interrumpe, comparte la parte dónde creas el adapter por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede funcionar sin problema, pero debes retornar `true` al usar `onItemLongClick`

```
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent lanzadera = new Intent(ActTiendaSeleccionar.this, ActCrudEquipos.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("objTienda", listaTiendas.get(position));
    bundle.putSerializable("objEmpresa", empresa);
    lanzadera.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(lanzadera);
    //* return false;
     return true;
  }
```

Recuerda lo que indica la documentación:

> Al usar [OnItemLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) , devuelve verdadero si la devolución de llamada consumió el clic largo,
>   falso de lo contrario

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys.  Efectivamente es como tu indicas.  He puesto a ```true``` el ```return``` y ahora al hacer una pulsación larga únicamente lanza una actividad.

Comment: Excelente @pellagofio , saludos!